# How to view errno in qt creator?

Tags: qt, gdb

I am debugging linux application in qt creator. Everything works fine, except I could not view the errno in the `locals and expressions` view.

Moreover, I could not invoke gdb command in qt creator, `p *__errno_location()` would not work. I tried add a temp variable to store the errno, but the temp variable would be optimized even with `-O0`.

Is there any other way to view errno within qt creator debugger?

Answer (score 1):

`errno` is funny because it is a thread-local.  Evaluating `errno`, or any thread local, in gdb requires some debug info -- though, IIRC, at least Fedora carries a special gdb patch to let just `errno` evaluation work without debug info.

On my machine (Fedora 22), I don't have glibc debug info, but it works:

```
(gdb) p errno
$1 = 2
```

So, maybe your distro doesn't have this special patch -- in which case installing the glibc debug info should work.

As to `__errno_location` -- first, nice try!  It should work.  But, if you don't have debug info, take a look at what gdb thinks of the function's type:

```
(gdb) p __errno_location
$2 = {<text variable, no debug info>} 0x3297420920 <__errno_location>
(gdb) ptype __errno_location
type = int ()
```

That is, gdb thinks it returns `int`!  This is a longstanding gdb oddity, which made some sense in the K&R days, but which is just an anachronism now.

Calling this function yields nonsense of course:

```
(gdb) p __errno_location()
$3 = -134416752
```

If you cast the function before calling it, you can get the right answer:

```
(gdb) p * ((int*(*)(void)) __errno_location)()
$4 = 2
```

Comment: but i'd like to know how to view it in qt.

Comment: Sorry.  Install glibc debuginfo.